# Retrieve the list of events from iCal with PHP

Tags: php, ios, icalendar

**Problem:**

Allow user to share all his iCal events so that we know when he is available/free at any time.

**Question:**

Is there any way (library, documentation or example) to get the events from Apple Calendar?
I've found some SO posts but did not find an answer yet. Where should I look at?

In Google calendar it is pretty clear what we have to do but in iCal is a mystery..

---

**Similar app with this functionality :**

- Calendly

Comment: This sounds like a user issue? When you say iCal, do you mean apple?   Most calendar applications have a sharing option when one can get the feed (the .ics) and subscribe to it in another calendar application.. EG: https://www.imore.com/how-share-calendar-events-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: I think you'll want to find a way to retrieve/create events from an iCloud Calendar. If I am correct you give as example Calendly, because you want dynamically to manage events in your calendar app. I hope to find your solution, because many users have the same problem.

Comment: @anmari Yes I am talking about apple calendar. I can't find any API for getting the events. On the other hand, Google Calendar has a nice documentation!
Getting the .ics will not solve my problem as it will only give me the current events and I will not get future events that he will add.

Comment: @anmari Calendly uses a one time password for syncing apple calendar. How are they doing that?

Comment: Subscribing via .ics (NOT import) means that your calendar application will check for updates and so future events will be shown, maybe not instantaneously.   NB Must SUBSCRIBE, NOT import.  https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/calendar/icl1022/mac

Comment: @anmari I see what you mean but I do not want the user to perform all this actions. Instead I want to sync the calendar with the one time password. Just like Calendly.com does it. Do you have any idea how this can be done?